# Image viewpoint render doesn't seem to be outputting to designated folder

Tags: blender, image-rendering

I'm new to Blender, and I only got it to save very simple, unshaded renders of a model. I want to save a transparent, high-res render of the model from the viewport. After setting up the model and camera, I tried to do a viewport image render. The popup with the final render appeared, but upon looking in the file I designated in Output > Format > Output, I found no image. Attempts in different file locations gave the same results. I'm using Blender 4.0.

I set the output to the full file path that went into my OneDrive Documents folder. Thinking the OneDrive might be causing some kind of issue, I made another attempt, designating a file made directly on my hard drive, but it also resulted in no actual output. Both times, I got the popup confirming that the image was rendered properly.